# tikz: transparent object (overlay) loses its transparency. Why?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw a (transparent) disk with tikz on top of some text in the
middle of the page so that the text is still readable.  The following MWE
correctly shows this for a red disk *if* the first `\blindtext` command is not
there/commented out. However, if it is there (so if there is some text before
the tikz picture), then the disk loses its transparency. I wonder how this can
be prevented (in case it matters: this is on macOS 12.1, TeXLive 2020).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
%% Commenting the following line *out* correctly shows the disk in full transparency.
%% However, with the following line the disk is only transparent with respect to
%% the text thereafter.
\blindtext[3] % comment in/out to see the difference
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.center)}]
  \pgfdeclarelayer{ink}
  \pgfsetlayers{main,ink}
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{ink}
    \draw[fill, color = red!95] (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: there is no transparency in your code. You are printing some text, then you print an opaque disk (which is above the text) and then you print some more text (which overwrites a part of the disk).

Comment: Hi Ulrike, thanks for your help. That indeed makes sense. I also tried to specify `opacity`, but there is still a 'difference' in color visible for text printed before and text printed after the object. How can one guarantee that the object is printed first/last no matter where it is placed in the .tex file? Does one need to work with `\AddToShipoutPicture` or so (?)

Comment: Yes, add it to shipout/background or shipout/foreground hook. With \AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(...){...}}

Comment: Hmmm... `\AddToHook` produces `Undefined control sequence` ... read that it's new since 2020 (but perhaps TeXLive 2020 is not sufficient?)

Comment: Note that PGF layering only controls the order in which the images are drawn within the tikzpicture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer (always a pleasure to see her help here, incredible work), I could find the following solution. Note that it required updating to TeXLive 2021.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0,0){
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.center)}]
  \pgfdeclarelayer{ink}
  \pgfsetlayers{main,ink}
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{ink}
    \draw[fill, color=red] (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

The above solution prints a picture on all pages. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629023/how-to-reset-clear-a-hook-or-how-to-print-a-background-picture-only-once) is a follow-up in case a picture should only appear on a single page, or in case it should appear on several (but not all pages).