# How to reset/clear a hook (or: how to print a background picture only once)

Tags: hooks, lthooks

I'd like to add a picture in the background of a single page, but if I use `\AddToHook` it appears on every page of the document. If I want to clear it after it appears on that specific page (so only one page), how can I do this? I thought `\ClearHookNext` would work but I get `Undefined control sequence` (macOS 12.1, latest TeXLive 2021).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0,0){%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.center)}]
   \draw[fill, color=red] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}
\blindtext[10]
% Trials:
% \RemoveFromHook{shipout/background}% removes all (so also the first one we wanted to print)
%\ClearHookNext{shipout/background}% Undefined control sequence
\end{document}
```

**Update:** A different, but related problem would then be how to switch off a hook after a couple of pages (when you don't know the exact page number beforehand as the content is variable in length). Using `\RemoveFromHook` at that point draws no background picture at all (although one would expect it to draw them between the `\AddToHook` and `\RemoveFromHook` commands):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0,0){%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.center)}]
   \draw[fill, color=red] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}
\blindtext[10]
\RemoveFromHook{shipout/background}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try using `\AddToHookNext` and add a blank line between `\blindtext[10]` and `\AddToHookNext`.  You can do that or check for the page number

Comment: ... thanks a lot, Phelype, that worked!

Comment: And how could one clear out the picture after several pages?

Comment: You mean you want a range of pages?  If so, try `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \ifnum\value{page}>2 \ifnum\value{page}<5 % only on page 3 to 4
    \put(0,0){%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.center)}]
       \draw[fill, color=red] (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  \fi\fi}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\AddToHookNext{<hook>}` which adds code to be executed only the next time the `<hook>` is called.  The document below prints 5 pages, and the third has a red circle in the middle:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[10] % blank line below required

\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0,0){%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.center)}]
   \draw[fill, color=red] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

The blank line between the first `\blindtext` and `\AddToHookNext` is needed so that TeX processes `\blindtext[10]` (breaking it into paragraphs and those paragraphs into pages, thus shipping pages out) and then when you call `\AddToHookNext` you are on the right page.  If you don't add the blank line, by the time you call `\AddToHookNext` TeX is still processing the first page (even though it has two full pages of content stored in memory), so the circle ends up in the wrong place.

---

Another way, if you want to place the circle in a specific page (rather than "right here") is to test for the page number:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=3 % only on page 3
    \put(0,0){%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.center)}]
       \draw[fill, color=red] (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  \fi}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to turn your code on and off in the hook in the middle of the document (page number unknown) then you need a finer-grained control provided by rules.

You can, as in the example below, label the circle code as `./mycircle`, and add another blank chunk of code labelled `./stop-mycircle`.  By default, both chunks added are executed (the second is blank, so it does no harm).  Then, when you want to deactivate the circle background you write

```latex
\DeclareHookRule{shipout/background}{./stop-mycircle}{voids}{./mycircle}
```

so that the presence of `./stop-mycircle` in the hook will stop `./mycircle` from executing.  Then you can write

```latex
\ClearHookRule{shipout/background}{./mycircle}{./stop-mycircle}
```

to remove that "`voids`" rule and allow `./mycircle` executing again.

The big advantage of this method is that you can use these commands on and off at your will: none will act destructively on the code you added to the hook, so you can always revert.  In fact, `\RemoveFromHook` is better, in most cases, replaced by `voids`.

Here is the code (whose output contains circles on pages 3, 4 and 5 only):

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}[./mycircle]{\put(0,0){%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.center)}]
    \draw[fill, color=red] (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}}}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}[./stop-mycircle]{}
\newcommand\circleon{%
  \ClearHookRule{shipout/background}{./mycircle}{./stop-mycircle}}
\newcommand\circleoff{%
  \DeclareHookRule{shipout/background}{./stop-mycircle}{voids}{./mycircle}}
\circleoff % initially off

\begin{document}
page 1 \clearpage
page 2 \clearpage
page 3 \circleon \clearpage % start showing on page 3
page 4 \clearpage
page 5 \clearpage
page 6 \circleoff \clearpage % no longer show on page 6
page 7 \clearpage
\end{document}
```

---

`\ClearHookNext` shouldn't be read as "clear the hook after the next execution", but as "clear the 'next execution' code", so it removes code added with `\AddToHookNext`.  To remove code added with `\AddToHook` you have to use either `\RemoveFromHook` or add another code label with a rule that `voids` the one you want to remove.

Comment: Hi Phelype. Thanks a lot. It would be really great to have a solution that shows how to switch a hook off on any page after `\AddToHook`. I don't know after which page I want to switch off the hook (so I don't know the page number beforehand). When I use `\RemoveFromHook{shipout/background}`, it doesn't even draw the first one, it draws none. So how can one switch off a hook at some (unknown) point later in the document? (see my Update)

Comment: @MariusHofert I added a method that allows you to turn the code in the hook on and off at will.  I think this will do what you need

Comment: Excellent, thanks again. I couldn't find a single good example in this direction, so hopefully this will be useful to many users.

Comment: This works, but in the first example, the command `\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}` is unnecessary. TikZ alone is enough to write a figure in the background. The same result can be obtained just using`\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw[fill, color=red] (current page.center) circle (2cm);`